# Remove shadow overlay on top edge of LinearLayout

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

[image]

As above: I have a sliding drawer in the form of a linear layout, this linear layout has a semi transparent black background gradient, however, it seems as those there is some sort of default overlay gradient applied to the TOP edge of the layout by default, is there any way to disable this?

tried:

```
<style name="NoOverlayShadow" parent="AppBaseTheme">
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

this code is from my app, and its working

```
  <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="actionBarStyle">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle" tools:ignore="NewApi">@style/Widget.Styled.ActionBar</item>
  </style>


 <style name="Widget.Styled.ActionBar" parent="Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="background">@android:color/transparent</item>
        <item name="android:background">@android:color/transparent</item>
 </style>
```

and in activity:

```
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_BAR_OVERLAY);
```

**Snapshot**:

[image]

Comment: Surely that will only apply to the actionbar? I am using a LinearLayout on top of another layout